# Make the full wrapper clickable

Tags: html, hyperlink, wrapper

I am trying to make my full wrapper clickable, For example, if they click on the white rectangle or the excerpt. For now, only the picture and title lead to the article.

Ideally, the listing item would have the same link as title and picture.

An example : https://dm-gaming.eu/pepites-autres/

My CSS:

```
.display-posts-listing .listing-item {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px #dedede;
    background-color:  #fff;
}
```

/*Pages de jeu*/

```
.display-posts-listing.jeu .title {
    position: absolute !important;
margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 3px;
margin-top: 0.2%;
    color: #111111;
font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.display-posts-listing.jeu .excerpt {
    position: absolute !important;
margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 3px;
margin-top: 2.6%;
    color: #111111;
}

.display-posts-listing.jeu .comments-link {
    position: absolute !important;
    margin-left: 250px;
margin-top: 45px;}

.display-posts-listing.jeu .title {
    position: absolute !important;
margin-right: 8px;
    margin-left: 3px; }

.display-posts-listing.jeu .category-display {
    position: absolute !important;
    margin-left: 75px;
margin-top: 47px;
font-size: 12px;}

.display-posts-listing.jeu .category-display {
    color: #fff; }

.display-posts-listing.jeu .category-display a {
    text-transform: none;
    border: solid 1px #aeaeae;
border-radius: 5px;
padding-left: 2px;
padding-right: 2px;
color: #030e4b;}

.display-posts-listing.jeu .date {          
        color: #808080; 
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 47.9px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0.3%;
    font-size: 12px;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px)

{.display-posts-listing.jeu .category-display {
    display: none !important;}}
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 1150px)

{.display-posts-listing.jeu .title {
    margin-top: 1px !important;}
}

    @media screen and (max-width: 1150px)

{.display-posts-listing.jeu .excerpt {
    margin-top: 0.8% !important;}
}

    @media screen and (max-width: 1150px)

{.display-posts-listing.jeu .excerpt {
    margin-top: 0.8% !important;}
}
```

My page code exemple

```
[display-posts post_type=”page” image_size="thumb" taxonomy="category" tax_term="broforce" tax_operator="AND"   wrapper="div" wrapper_class="display-posts-listing jeu" posts_per_page=10  meta_key="_thumbnail_id" category_display="post_tag" category_label="" include_date="true" date_format="d/m/Y" include_excerpt="true" include_excerpt_dash="false" category_display="true"]
```

Page html code :
view-source:https://dm-gaming.eu/pepites-autres/

I would like the class "listing-items" to be clickable everywhere, not just the title or the picture

```
<div class="vc_separator wpb_content_element vc_separator_align_center vc_sep_width_100 vc_sep_pos_align_left vc_separator_no_text vc_custom_1674482909819  vc_custom_1674482909819"><span class="vc_sep_holder vc_sep_holder_l"><span style="border-color:#111111;" class="vc_sep_line"></span></span><span class="vc_sep_holder vc_sep_holder_r"><span style="border-color:#111111;" class="vc_sep_line"></span></span>
</div></div></div></div></div><div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  vc_custom_1673538964140">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <p style="text-align: center;"></p><div class="display-posts-listing jeu"><div class="listing-item"><a class="image" href="https://dm-gaming.eu/pepites-autres/multiversus-ujess-31/"><img width="125" height="70" src="https://dm-gaming.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Multiversus-le-nouveau-Super-Smash-Bros-decouvrez-le-en-60-secondes-e1659691382245.jpg" class="attachment-thumb size-thumb wp-post-image" alt="Multiversus, le nouveau Super Smash Bros ? Découvrez le en 60 secondes" loading="lazy" srcset="https://dm-gaming.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Multiversus-le-nouveau-Super-Smash-Bros-decouvrez-le-en-60-secondes-e1659691382245.jpg 800w, https://dm-gaming.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Multiversus-le-nouveau-Super-Smash-Bros-decouvrez-le-en-60-secondes-e1659691382245-300x169.jpg 300w, https://dm-gaming.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Multiversus-le-nouveau-Super-Smash-Bros-decouvrez-le-en-60-secondes-e1659691382245-125x70.jpg 125w, https://dm-gaming.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Multiversus-le-nouveau-Super-Smash-Bros-decouvrez-le-en-60-secondes-e1659691382245-768x432.jpg 768w, https://dm-gaming.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Multiversus-le-nouveau-Super-Smash-Bros-decouvrez-le-en-60-secondes-e1659691382245-24x14.jpg 24w, https://dm-gaming.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Multiversus-le-nouveau-Super-Smash-Bros-decouvrez-le-en-60-secondes-e1659691382245-36x20.jpg 36w, https://dm-gaming.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Multiversus-le-nouveau-Super-Smash-Bros-decouvrez-le-en-60-secondes-e1659691382245-48x27.jpg 48w" sizes="(max-width: 125px) 100vw, 125px"/></a> <a class="title" href="https://dm-gaming.eu/pepites-autres/multiversus-ujess-31/">MultiVersus 60 SECS #31</a> <span class="date">08/08/2022</span> <span class="category-display"><span class="category-display-label"></span> <a href="https://dm-gaming.eu/category/multiversus/">MultiVersus</a>, <a href="https://dm-gaming.eu/category/un-jeu-en-60-secondes/">Un Jeu En 60 Secondes</a></span> <span class="excerpt">Le concurrent à Super Smash Bros en incarnant Superman ou Bugs Bunny !</span></div></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide some code so that we can help you out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML code as well CSS code to the question instead of comment.

Comment: done, sorry for the delay I am not very familiar with stackoverflow posts

Comment: It's not about SO posts. It's about basic communication. We can't help with what we can't see. Please see [ask] and take the [tour] for tips. You should be able to capture rendered HTML from a web page.

Comment: Hope it answers the comment, I read both links but I am not very sure to be totaly following :(